# events associated with scroll bars for JFXpanel

Tags: java, javafx

What are the events associated with scroll up and scroll down? i want to create two buttons as top and down instead of using scroll up and down to move JFXpanel up and down. what events should i associate with these buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the `ScrollPane` element and the [vvalue](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#vvalueProperty) property, which is a `double` value by default between `0.0` and `1.0`, representing state of being scrolled to the top and bottom respectively.

So, to scroll to the bottom:

```
scrollpane.setVvalue(1);
```

And to scroll to the top:

```
scrollpane.setVvalue(0);
```

You can use [`ScrollPane.setVmax()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#setVmax%28double%29) and [`ScrollPane.setVmin()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#setVmin%28double%29) to set other values for [vmin](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#vminProperty) (default 0.0) and [vmax](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#vmaxProperty) (default 1.0).

Here is a handy function to animate the scroll:

```
public void scrollVAnimate(ScrollPane scrollPane, double duration, double toVal)
{
    TimelineBuilder.create()
        .keyFrames(
            new KeyFrame(
                Duration.millis(duration),
                new KeyValue(scrollPane.vvalueProperty(), toVal)
            )).build()
            .play();
}
```

Usage:

```
// scroll to the bottom, animated
this.scrollVAnimate(scrollpane, 300, 1);
```

You can assign these actions to a button either using FXML or Java code. In both cases we assume that `scrollpane` is a field in your controller.

### 1. Using FXML

Create a method in your controller:

```
public void onBtnDownPressed(MouseEvent event)
{
    this.scrollpane.setVvalue(1);
}
```

Add it to the button in your controller's .fxml:

```
<Button text="Scroll to bottom" onAction="#onBtnDownPressed"></Button>
```

### 2. Using [setOnAction](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBase.html#setOnAction%28javafx.event.EventHandler%29) in Java:

```
button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event)
    {
        scrollpane.setVvalue(1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Dreen. It seems to be a brilliant answer, but i want to programmatically scroll JFXPanel since i have set Scene with it. Scene can not be associated with ScrollPane so pls help referring to JFXPanel.

Comment: Well, I don't know if there is a Swing solution, but couldn't you just wrap your content in a `ScrollPane` that you put into the `JFXPanel` ?